# Reduce Resolution of Wig

Tags: java, r, bioinformatics

I have some very large [WIG](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/help/wiggle.html) files from ChIP-seq binding profiles, but I wish to upload the wig files to some online genome browser. Therefore I need to reduce the size of the wig file, by lowering resolution.

Say I don't need a 100 bp window, I can accept 1000 bp window to visualize the binding profile. Not sure if there are some effective algorithms to do that?

I can implement using java or R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the most convenient way is to use SPP to lower the resolution of Wig while generating them from Bam.

Following scripts might be useful.

```
bamtowig("treat.bam","control.bam","name","OutDir",150, 50)
tag.dens<-get.smoothed.tag.density(chip.data, control.tags=input.data, bandwidth=bandwidth, step=step) 
writewig(tag.dens, fname=paste(nam, ".TagDens.bd",bandwidth,".st",step,".wig", sep=""),paste("Tag Density", bandwidth, step))
```

Another way is parsing the wig directly, as wig is text file, you can write a script that read the wig line by line and merge to the large windows should be an option. For large windows, average value can be used.